# Make word bold with setValue in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

How to make the replaced word bold and underline when using TemplateProcessor in PHPWord? Found solutions are very old (2016).

I tried to create my function, to edit xml document, but done file is crashing.

My code:

```
$path = public_path()."/example/dogovor.docx";

$document = new TemplateProcessor($path);

$document->setValue('student-name', 'Alex');

$document->saveAs(public_path("documents/test.docx"));
```

Tried this function:

```
private function makeWordBold($str, $hex=null, $style='b'): string
    {
        $cor = $hex ? "<w:color w:val='".$hex."'/>" : "";
        $before="/w:t/w:r<w:r><w:rPr>".$cor."<w:".$style."/>/w:rPr<w:t xml:space='preserve'>";
        $after='/w:t/w:r<w:r><w:t>';
        return $before.$str.$after;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = public_path()."/example/dogovor.docx";

$document = new TemplateProcessor($path);
$word = new TextRun();
$word->addText('Alex', array('underline' => 'single', 'bold' => true));
$document->setComplexValue('student-name', $word);
$document->saveAs(public_path("documents/test.docx"));
```

Comment: When answering, it's recommended to share some context instead of just posting a snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.

Comment: Not working for me, giving error `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\AbstractElement::__construct()` any suggestion? Please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make my own code, so it can handle if there are more than one `<strong>` tag or there is `<em>` tag too in one sentence. The idea is I make my own unique tags to replace the HTML tags.

```
$yourInputString = "The last word of this sentence is <strong>bold</strong>";

$yourInputString = str_replace("<strong>","|@@|CUSTOMID=01", $yourInputString);
$yourInputString = str_replace("</strong>","|@@|", $yourInputString);

$yourInputString = str_replace("<em>","|@@|CUSTOMID=02", $yourInputString);
$yourInputString = str_replace("</em>","|@@|", $yourInputString);

// $yourInputString = "The last word of this sentence is |@@|CUSTOMID=01bold|@@|"

$exploded = explode("|@@|", $yourInputString);

/* $exploded = [
    'The last word of this sentence is',
    'CUSTOMID=01bold',
    '',
]
*/

$sentence = new TextRun();

for ($j=0; $j < count($exploded); $j++) {
    // I take 11 first character and check whether it's bold or italic
    if (substr($exploded[$j],0,11) == 'CUSTOMID=01') {
        //BOLD TEXT
        $sentence->addText(substr($exploded[$j],11), array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => '11', 'bold' => true));
    }elseif (substr($exploded[$j],0,11) == 'CUSTOMID=02') {
        //ITALIC TEXT
        $sentence->addText(substr($exploded[$j],11), array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => '11', 'italic' => true));
    }else{
        //DEFAULT TEXT
        $sentence->addText(substr($exploded[$j],0), array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => '11'));
    }
}

$templateProcessor->setComplexValue('some_placeholder', $sentence);
```